# How to render different components in different placeholders in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, components, rendering

so i've been learning reactjs for the past week and i had an issue : i wanted to make a website and created a header component ( just a div component ) and a footer component (div also) and i dont know how can i render them both in different placeholders :

```
<header id="header"></header>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  </body>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
```

**i want to render the header component in the header tag and in the same time i want to render the footer component in the footer tag**

here's what i tried :

```
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById("header"));
ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById("footer"));
```

but it's giving me an **Error: Target container is not a DOM element.**
so i guess react doesn't allow this multiple rendering, so what's the solution?

Comment: Put the `<script/>` tag under the footer one

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @Jayce444 tried it, dosent work, it gives only the first element i wanted to render

Comment: @ViniciusKatata a website is usually made of three parts, the header, the body and the footer that's why i thought of making every part in a component, and when i wanted to render it, it dosent work

Comment: Hmm, you might be confusing `header` tag with `head`, aren't you?

Comment: @ViniciusKatata no i am not, to clarify things  for us header is the part where we create the appBar/navBar so it's not **head**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***index.js***

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>Header</header>
      <footer>Fotter</footer>
    </div>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: You could import your `Header` and `Footer` components and use them

Answer (score -1):

You should place header and footer element inside body element:

```
<body>
    <header id="header"></header>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <footer id="footer"></footer>
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
</body>
```